# Kivy, python - Include kv files in others kv files

Tags: python, kivy

How I can include kivy file from different folder?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since patch https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/1720 (merged on 7 Feb 2014), KV language has an 'include' directive.

You can `#:include theNameOfkivyfile.kv` in a KV file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `#:import TheNameOfkivyfile FolderOfAkivyfile.TheNameOfkivyfile`